# Change type of for loop to forEach?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have created a JSONArray `"listsOfEmployee"` and i put a lot of data in it.

I have a loop:

`for (int i = 0; i < listOfEmployee.length(); i++)`

I use the variable `int i = 0` for example in this way:

`JSONObject currentEmploye = listOfEmployee.getJSONObject(i);`

Can I convert this loop to forEach to get the current item/employee? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It possible, you can try this when use java 7 or lower

```
 for(Object obj: listOfEmployee){
    if (obj instanceof JSONObject ) {
        parse((JSONObject) obj);
    }
 }
```

and java 8
    
    `array.forEach(item -> {
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) item;
        parse(obj);
    });`